# DC motor efficiency which formula to use?

Tags: dc-motor, efficiency

I'm doing a lab report for a shunt DC motor evaluation. I seem to be stuck on the efficiency vs torque of the motor.

I have plotted a graph of measured \$\frac{P_{out}}{P_{in}}\cdot 100\%\$, which shows that the motor becomes less effcient with more load. (Increments from 0.1Nm to 1.1Nm then stalls.)

This is fine as it shows me that the motor is running aroud 50% efficiency at 0.1Nm and 18% at 1Nm.

My issue is when I try to use some more involved formulas the graph seem to flip around using the recorded values and shows that the motor is most efficient just before stall condition up to 95% so I'm unsure which to use.

The formulas I have been given are

$$ P_{out}= 2\pi T \frac{N}{60} \\P_{in} = V_f I_f + V_a I_a$$

Calculate these then put into the previous formula \$\frac{P_{out}}{P_{in}}\cdot 100\%\$.

Any ideas why the results are flipping?

To add here are my results from the Lab I have calculated the Pin and Pout using Ohms law V.I from the armature values Pin and Field values Pout i have also added the equation 5,6,7 calculations on the right hand side

[image]

Here are my calculations using the Eq 5,6,7 from above excell doing the calculations

Hopefully this all makes sense thanks

[image: calculations]

Comment: Do you have a reference that says to add the armature power to the source power.  This is not right.  The power in comes only from the source, not the armature.

Comment: Hi there yes the Pin formula above is what is stated in my lab script. Its a power frame system there is a link to the student manual here which shows the formula. Its under assignement 1 DC shunt motor and evaluation http://www.slideshare.net/ScottAnderson114/feedback-powerframes-electrical-machines-students-manual

Comment: Im just thinking for my first calculation of effciency which seems to be working I am using armature voltage and current for Pin which they state as V1,I1 and field voltage and current as Pout which is V2,I2. I have tried to swap the values over in my Power formula but it gives high results so im assuming it isnt correct.  Thanks

Comment: OK, is your lab on a shunt motors?  If it is, do you see increasing current and decreasing speed as you increase the load?  If this is shunt, the field current should be constant assuming the power supply voltage is not changing.  What units are you measuring N in?

Comment: Yes it is on shunt motors. Speed recorded in rpm. The speed fluctuated slighty however id say the values are relatively linear througout the range. The torque was increase in increments of .1Nm

Comment: If the motor is a shunt motor, you should revise the question to state that. Also the tags should be DC-motor and efficiency. The series tag is not appropriate, but the shunt tag may not really be useful.

Comment: Apologies done. thats me getting mixed up

Comment: Do you have the nameplate information for the motor?  How many Watts or horse power is the motor?  What is the nominal running current?

Comment: Its actually a training rig so the windings are changeable on an external resistance box. If you look at this link http://www.slideshare.net/ScottAnderson114/feedback-powerframes-electrical-machines-students-manual this is the exact unit we are using. This is assignment 1 a DC shunt motor with the resistance box shorted out to zero ohms. thanks

Comment: The unit itself is a powerframes DC Compound wound motor 63-120 examples of the units can be found here http://www.feedback-instruments.com/pdf/brochures/60-070_datasheet_Powerframes_Core_System_12_2013.pdf. Thanks

Comment: Could be a problem with inaccurate torqueductor or torque measuring setup or current/voltage instrument. It is obviously that the efficiency can't be overunity. Still it isn't clear how did you get Pin and Pout for the table results 1.1 and what they rapresent.

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense. rpm should _reduce_ as torque load is increased, not increase. Also your output power 'results' are obviously wrong. 1.1Nm@3314rpm **cannot** be less power than 0.1Nm@3209rpm (it should be over 10 times higher). So your Excel spreadsheet must have some error(s) in it (incorrect formula, wrong cells referenced?).

Comment: Thanks for your comments on this particular set of results the resistance box connected to the motor has been shorted would this have something to do with it? making it zero ohms resistance? With regards to the first table Pin was calculate using Varmature.Iarmature. Pout was calculated using Vfield.Ifield.

Comment: So i have just checked my results on the series motor section.The efficiency using both methods mentioned above comes out with the same outcome. I am starting to think it must be something to do with shorting the resistance box on the shunt motor setup that is causing the unusual readings

Comment: There are two parts to the first assignment one is with the link fitted across the resistance box and one is with resistance of 180ohms and 317ohms. I can see the effects of the link fitted and the different ohmic values but does anyone know why the first test would be carried out? it must be to show something but I'm unsure why you would do it

Comment: The resistance box is used to reduce voltage and current in the field coil. Shorting it out simply ensures that the field coil gets full voltage. The formulae you have shown us are correct - the problem is in the data and/or spreadsheet calculations.

Answer (score 1):

\$ V_f I_f\$ is a pure loss, it is needed for the excitation. If the excitation winding would be made of superconductor, then you could fill the current only once and close the windings contacts. The other solution is to use permanent magnets instead.
Then you have a copper loss \$I_a^2 R_a\$ and a iron loss in the rotor \$P_{fe}=k_{fe}\Omega\$, as the rotor field is AC, but let's say that you can omit this for simpler calculation.
Post the formulas you did before, so we can take a look and discuss.

EDIT:
You could rewrite the efficiency formula from loss. \$P_{in}=P_{EM} + P_{loss} = P_{EM}+ P_{Cu}+P_{Fe}\$, where \$P_{EM}\$ is the electromagnetic energy and it is converted into a mechanical energy, so let's make a new formula:
$$\eta=\dfrac{P_{mech}}{P_{mech}+P_{loss}}=\dfrac{P_{mech}}{P_{mech}+V_fI_f+I_a^2R_a}$$
The formula is omits the iron losses. At least you won't get over 100% efficiency, additionally you need a resistance of the armature \$R_a\$

Answer (score 1):

Eq5, Eq6 and Eq7 are correct for a motor with a separately excited field. If the motor has a shunt field, the field and armature voltages would be equal. Since they are not quite equal, the motor is treated like it has a separately excited field.

The Excel spreadsheet must be set up for some other conditions. Since nothing you have posted indicates that anything else is applicable, Eq5, Eq6 and Eq7 should be used.

The RPM increasing with load would seem to indicate that something is going on that is not explained. However I don't see a reason that should have much effect the efficiency very much.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Charles the form would not let me add to the original post again. I have edited the results table to show equation 5,6,7 along side as you can see the efficiencies of both sets in excell do not correspond

Comment: The second set must be closer to the actual efficiency. Obviously the efficiency can not be greater than 100%. There must be a problem with the measurements. Is there any possibility that the RPM figures were entered in the reverse order such that the RPM listed for full load is actually belongs at the top of the column, minimum load?

Comment: Yes I did notice it jumped above 100% it must be must be reading error on that one. No I dont think so we had a table to input them into and recorded each in turn. My main issue at the minute is dont know which to write into the report. Strange the two are so far out?

Answer (score 1):

What I think is going on here is that you are operating on the lighter than peak efficiency part to the curve.  A shunt DC motor has two places where the efficiency goes to zero.  One is when speed=0.  The other is where torque=0.  The maximum efficiency of a DC motor is at higher speeds when lightly loaded.  The measurements seem to have some error because you can't be more than 100% efficient.  Putting that aside, the way you get what you call inverted is by going from very light loads up to the peak.  After the peak you start to go down.  At this site; [Electric Equipment](http://machineryequipmentonline.com/electric-equipment/dc-motors-part1/)  You'll find this graph;

[image: DC Motor Typical Graph]

Notice how starting at very low loads the efficency is going up as you increase the load.  Effiency is the green curve.